# Predicting confidence interval with statsmodels

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am building a linear model like so:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import summary_table
import numpy as np
import random

x = np.arange(1,101, 1)
y = random.sample(range(1,1000), 100)

X = sm.add_constant(x)
regr = sm.OLS(y, X)
fit = regr.fit()

st, data, ss2 = summary_table(fit, alpha=0.05)
```

I can determine the standard error and confidence intervals from `data`.

Now I want to predict what the confidence interval is on new data which I am trying like so:

```
new_data = [102, 103, 104, 105]

fit.get_prediction(new_data)
```

but this returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-168-372d2610946d>", line 14, in <module>
    fit.get_prediction(new)

  File "/Users/spotter/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py", line 2138, in get_prediction
    weights=weights, row_labels=row_labels, **kwds)

  File "/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/_prediction.py", line 163, in get_prediction
    predicted_mean = self.model.predict(self.params, exog, **pred_kwds)

  File "/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py", line 261, in predict
    return np.dot(exog, params)

ValueError: shapes (1,4) and (2,) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you trained your model with an intercept, you also need to include it when creating `new_data` (= adding a column of 1's).

```
new_data = sm.add_constant([102, 103, 104, 105])
result = fit.get_prediction(new_data)
result.conf_int()
```